# MS Word VBA Style and Pagebreak Cleanup

Tags: vba, ms-word

My company's workflow currently includes a process where we export documentation from a repository, clean it up a bit, and send it down the line for review/approval. The "clean it up a bit" involves running a macro that, among other things, does a find/replace on styles to change them from what comes out of the repository, to what is specified by our document template. So, for example, the repository gives us a style for "p_body," and we need that to be "body". This macro works pretty well, except for a couple of things that I'd like to see if we can polish up.

The first issue is that the repository tends to behave somewhat unpredictably when it comes to the styles that it delivers. To use the example from above, instead of tagging all of the "p_body" text in that style, it comes back with "p_body", "p_body_1", "p_body_1_1," and the like. Currently, the style switching in the macro is all hard-coded, so in order for the macro to fix something, it has to know it exists. Thus, if the repository spits out a style that's not already in the macro, it won't get fixed. I know that if I was dealing with an HTML doc, I could use a regular expression to find all versions of the "p_body" style, and replace them with "body." Is there a way to use such more intelligent find/replace version instead of hard-coding each style that needs to be replaced?

The second issue will take a separate question to fix, so it's now being snipped out.

For posterity, here's what one of the macro find/replace blocks looks like:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("p_body")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("body")
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: You should be using the range object rather than the selection object.

Comment: More information is needed about this page break issue. I don't see anything in the code you shared that is removing page breaks. You might consider making that a separate question and sharing the code you have. Of course, if you do that, update this question by removing the paragraph about the page breaks.

Comment: If replacing a style removes a page break it suggests that the original style included a page break before but the replacement style didn’t.

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with the style name variations on p_body and others try this. You fill the StyName1 array with the names to find, and in the StyName2 array put the replacement names. It must be a one-for-one match-up.

This is just one of many ways to code it.

```
Sub StyleNames()
    Dim StyName1 As Variant, StyName2 As Variant
    StyName1 = Array("p_body", "p_bold")
    StyName2 = Array("body", "bold")
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim findStyName As String, replaceName As String
    
    For i = LBound(StyName1) To UBound(StyName1)
        findStyName = StyName1(i)
        replaceName = StyName2(i)
        FindAndReplaceStyles findStyName, replaceName
    Next
    
End Sub

Private Function FindAndReplaceStyles(ByRef findStyName As String, ByRef replaceName As String)
    Dim sty As Word.Style, aStory As Word.Range
    For Each sty In ActiveDocument.Styles
        If InStr(1, sty.NameLocal, findStyName) Then
            For Each aStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
                With aStory.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Format = True
                    .Forward = True
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .Style = sty.NameLocal
                    .Text = ""
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.Style = replaceName
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Execute Replace:=Word.wdReplaceAll
                End With
            Next
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: This works, but I'll need a chain of similar ones to get at all the different styles that are covered in our template. What's the best way of chaining these together?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is a step backward; if we had a constant stream of starting styles to work with, I could just hard-code a set of find/replace statements as seen above, and we'd be all set.

Comment: *UPDATE* I went back to the original suggestion and managed to get it working with multiple styles! Not sure what I did this time that I wasn't doing before, but... this has potential to work.